# SharePoint 2013 Site Mailbox address different from expectation

Tags: site-mailboxes

I created a site mailbox on the Quality site for `companyservices.sharepoint.com`.

The site mailbox sent me a welcome email informing me that the email address was `SMO-Quality@companyservices.com`. I expected it to be `Quality@companyservices.sharepoint.com`. I don't understand why the former is the email address.

This is the site URL: https://companyservices.sharepoint.com/Quality/layout..etc.

Can someone explain? Also, is the site mailbox address viewable somewhere on the site?

Comment: AFAIK and in my experience, that is how site mail boxes operate, the later would be if you mail enabled a library.

Comment: @Eric. I was just going by the info here https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Overview-Use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-with-your-team-45fb1ef2-19f5-4bf5-b6e2-8f3f77c09221 that said "After a site mailbox is set up for your site, a new email account is created that uses the name of your site. For example, let’s say you have a team site that uses this URL: http://contosobistro.sharepoint.com/HRTeamSite. The email address for that site mailbox will be HRTeamSite@contosobistro.sharepoint.com" but this was my first one, so I haven't had any experience as you have. So I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Are you using dirsync at all to synchornize local AD accounts to your tenant? I've found a lot of their documentation is plain wrong when it comes to dirsynced tenants, and this might be the case, ours is dirsyned and exhibited the same behavior you see.

Comment: Thanks for the lead on dirsync. I have passed that along to the person who knows what you are talking about. And that is not me. But maybe it will give him some insights. Thanks for replying.